# How to enable/install kernel-debuginfo linux-4.14.14 on amzn-linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, debugging

I'm on an amzn-linux instance which by default runs linux-4.9. I've compiled and booted linux-4.14.14 from source and I've compiled systemtap from source. Now I'd like to get them both working nicely together. Systemtap requires linux-debuginfo package. I'm running into a myriad of issues just trying to enable this or get it installed:

- amzn-main-debuginfo yum repo only provides kernel-debuginfo-4.9
- I cannot find a kernel-debuginfo-4.14.14 package
- i cannot find kernel-debuginfo-4.14.14 source code so I can compile it from scratch
- I cannot find a CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO option for `make menuconfig` for linux-4.14.14
- if I manually add CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y to linux-4.14.14/.config it gets deleted before compilation

If there's any way to fix any one of the above things, I think I can get this to work.

Comment: It really is in there. Kernel hacking ---> Compile-time checks and compiler options ---> Compile the kernel with debug info.

Comment: Actually as I just discovered, it's not in there for arch/x86. To add it for arch/x86, it's necessary to go through some tomfoolery with Kconfig.  Not exactly the easiest path to enabling it.

Comment: Huh? You never mentioned anything about trying to use an x86 kernel. I guess I'll have to wish you luck with that.

Comment: well, this is an ec2 instance that for whatever reason was defaulting to arch/x86 when I run `make config`.